# How to query many to many relation tables in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i am trying to query many to many relation for my get api call. i have three table as shown here but i am not using pivot table.

[image]

This is my Projects model class and this the function

```
  public function projectRewd()
   {

     return $this 
               ->belongsToMany('App\Rewards','rewards','project_id','reward_id');


   }
```

And this is my Rewards model class and function

```
public function projectShip()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shipping_location','shipping_location','projects_id','rewards_id');

    }
```

This is my api controller function

```
Route::get('projects/{id}', function($id) {
    $proj = Projects::whereHas('projectRewd', function($q)
    {       
        $q->where('id', $id);         
    });                       
    return $proj;

 });
```

i am using this link for api call

```
http://localhost:8000/api/projects/1
```

i want to extract rewards data and shipping_location data associate with project_id.

i am getting this error

```
"message": "Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder could not be converted to string"
```

i check and tried all related error from different post.

i also search and tried many technique. Cant solve my problem.
Please suggest me how to do this??
can i do this type of query in larvel without using pivot table??

Answer (score 0):

Your closure-based controller returns your query-builder object. Not a project. You need to retrieve results from the query by fetching e.g. the first result (`->first()`) or all (`->get()`).

```
Route::get('projects/{id}', function($id) {
    $proj = Projects::whereHas('projectRewd', function($q)
    {       
        $q->where('id', $id);         
    })->first();                       
    return $proj;

 });
```

**Referencing $id:**

The reason why $id is unknown, is that the closure doesn't know about it.
You can pass it to the closure using `use(...)`.

```
Route::get('projects/{id}', function($id) {
    $proj = Projects::whereHas('projectRewd', function($q) use ($id)
    {       
        ...
```

**Further:**

Your whereHas query looks incorrect to me:

```
$q->where('id', $id);
```

Apparently `$id` is the project id. But the 'id' column in projectRewd is the primary key of projectRewd (unless you have modified the defaults).

I assume you want to query all projects that have at least one projectRewd:

```
Route::get('projects/{id}', function($id) {
        $proj = Projects::has('projectRewd')->first();                       
        return $proj;

     });
```

And if you want to eager load the joined tables:

```
Route::get('projects/{id}', function($id) {
        $proj = Projects::with('projectRewd. projectShips')->has('projectRewd')->first();                       
        return $proj;
    });
```

Comment: its getting me this "message": "Undefined variable: id" and when i put 1 instead of $id in $q->where('id', $id) gives this error. "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'rewards' (SQL: select * from `projects` where exists (select * from `rewards` inner join `rewards` on `rewards`.`id` = `rewards`.`reward_id` where `projects`.`id` = `rewards`.`project_id` and `id` = 1))"

Comment: I think my model code is not joining with shipping_location.

Comment: i appreciate for your suggestion. i am trying to make it work. it seems like my problem is in the model classes. I combine these(projectRewd,  projectShip) functions in Project model and trying to join the tables i am getting errors sql violation.   public function projectRewd()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rewards','rewards', 'projects_id');
       
   }  public function projectShip()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shipping_location', 'shipping_locations','reward_id','project_id');
      
   }

Comment: i get this error "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'rewards' (SQL: select * from `projects` where exists (select * from `rewards` inner join `rewards` on `rewards`.`id` = `rewards`.`rewards_id` where `projects`.`id` = `rewards`.`projects_id`) limit 1)",

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Builder model because you forgot to add `->first()` or `->get()`.

You should write:

```
$proj = Projects::whereHas('projectRewd', function($q){       
        $q->where('id', $id);         
})->first();
```

Comment: Hi Marius and welcome to SO. Why repeating the answer?

Comment: I think we wrote at the same time. Didn't see the previous answer.

Comment: hii guys thanks for your suggestion. I just realized my tables are not many to many and it is not good design. For many to many generally it use pivot table. Still i am not able to solve my problem even i use pivot table. is it better to ask new question for my problem?? or should i edit/modify my question??